# How can i check if datatable is empty or not

Tags: c#

I would like to check if datatable is empty or not. I wrote a code but it does not work and i do not know why.

```
    if(dataTable1.Rows.Count == 0)
  {
     //Some code
  }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. _We need to see how the `dataTable1` was populated._

Comment: you should show the ```datatable1.datasource``` how you are doing it!

Answer (score -1):

If your are using SqlDataReader then you can use **HasRow** property to check if there is any rows or not. False means table has no data. True means table has data.

```cs
if(dataTable1.HasRow){//true
//Table has data
}
else{
//table is empty
}
```

Comment: `Datatable` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't have **HasRow** property. How is this an answer?

Comment: You are not using database? Please provide more detail. How is your datatable created? From where do you get data in datatable?

Comment: Have a read at this
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer